# My Syntax is correct or not

Tags: php

I have to check my database table value using phpBt id don't know how to do comparison. Can you please give me some idea how to compare?

```
 if($property->status=='new') {
   <div class='status sold'>$property->status</div>
 } else {
   <div class='status new'>$property->status</div>
 }
 </div>
```

Comment: Didn't get your question. Can you elaborate with more information?

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: tip : use phtml as the file type :)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the `php` & `html`. It should be -

```
   <?php 
            if($property->status=='new') 
            {
   ?>
            <div class='status sold'><?php $property->status ?></div>
   <?php
            }
            else 
            {
   ?>
            <div class='status new'><?php $property->status ?></div>
   <?php
            }
   ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what errors your code produces, you can run it from the command prompt as follows:

```
php filename.php
```

You cannot place html code inside of php code without a php statement such as echo. You can fix your code as follows:

```
if($property->status=='new')
{
   echo "<div class=\"status new\">{$property->status}</div>";
}
else 
{
   echo "<div class=\"status sold\">{$property->status}</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`php` and `HTML` cannot be mixed like this if you want to use `PHP` with `HTML` use `single quote` for `html` or do it like below

```
 <?php if($property->status=='new')
            {?>
            <div class='status sold'><?php echo $property->status?></div>
          <?php   }
            else 
            {?>
            <div class='status new'><?php echo $property->status?></div>
          <?php   }?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most maintainable solution, I suggest you use output buffers. They don't require you to constantly open and close your php tags (`<?php`, `?>`). But they provide many benefits

```
<?php 
ob_start();
if($property->status=='new'){
    echo "sold";
}
else{
    echo "new";
}
$otherClass = ob_get_clean();
echo "<div class='status {$otherClass}'>{$property->status}</div>"
?>
```

This scales up really nicely, if you use it cleverly or correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. This will reduce line of code as well

```
 <div class="status <?php echo (($property->status=='new') ? 'sold' : 'new'); ?>"><?php echo $property->status; ?></div>
```